# google app engine cron gives file permissione issues

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, cron, file-permissions

I have started a cron in google app engine and I write some content to a file test.txt but when I run the cron in http://localhost:8000/cron in my dev server this gives me 500 error with this output.

```
 File "/base/data/home/apps/s~stock-analysis-1344/1.393612282659426384/hello.py", line 8, in get 
 f = open("test.txt","w") #opens file with name of "test.txt"
 IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'test.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

[The standard GAE sandbox](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#Python_The_sandbox) doesn't give write access to the filesystem:

> An App Engine application cannot:
>
> - write to the filesystem. Applications must use [the App Engine datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore) for storing persistent data. Reading from the filesystem
>     is allowed, and all application files uploaded with the application
>     are available.

The app can however write to files in a Google Cloud Storage bucket. See  [Reading and Writing to Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage) and/or [App Engine and Google Cloud Storage Sample](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/app-engine-cloud-storage-sample).